# JQuery Invalid or unexpected token and wait for loop to finish first

Tags: jquery, promise, async-await, unexpected-token

**Code**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   var block;
   if(i < 16) block = `<div class="wrapper"><div class="gap" id="imem_ingess${i}"></div><div class="container"><div class='title'>IMEM ingress ${i} Graph</div><div class="description">hey1</div></div><div class="pt-2 pb-2"></div><div class="chart-container" id="imem_ingess${i}_chart_container" style="position: relative; height:200rem; width:95vw; display: block;"><canvas id="imem_ingess${i}_chart" style="height: 30%; width: 30%;  display: block;"></canvas></div><div class="pt-4 pb-5"></div><div class="chart-container" id="imem_ingess${i}_chart_container2" style="position: relative; height:80rem; width:95vw; display: block;"><canvas id="imem_ingess${i}_chart2" style="height: 30%; width: 30%;  display: block;"></canvas></div></div>`;
   else block = `<div class="wrapper"><div class="gap" id="imem_egess${i-16}"></div><div class="container"><div class='title'>IMEM egress ${i-16} Graph</div><div class="description">hey2</div></div><div class="pt-2 pb-2"></div><div class="chart-container" id="imem_egess${i-16}_chart_container" style="position: relative; height:200rem; width:95vw; display: block;"><canvas id="imem_egess${i-16}_chart" style="height: 30%; width: 30%;  display: block;"></canvas></div><div class="pt-4 pb-5"></div><div class="chart-container" id="imem_egess${i-16}_chart_container2" style="position: relative; height:80rem; width:95vw; display: block;"><canvas id="imem_egess${i-16}_chart2" style="height: 30%; width: 30%;  display: block;"></canvas></div></div>`;

   $('#imem_statistics_page').append(block);​
}
```

---

**Issues**:

**1)** This code doesn't compile and it's throwing a syntax error.
**2)** I want to wait for the loop to finish before executing the remaining code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a U+200B (ZWSP) after the last semicolon.

Comment: ah that fixed the compile error! Thanks sm!

Comment: `Secondly...` You don't need to do anything. Your code will finish `for` loop then only it will proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your first question is solved, here is second answer for waiting for `loop`.

```
<script>

    const forLoop = async _ => {
        console.log('Start')
        //...

        for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            var block;
            if (i < 16) block = `<div class="wrapper"><div class="gap" id="imem_ingess${i}"></div><div class="container"><div class='title'>IMEM ingress ${i} Graph</div><div class="description">hey1</div></div><div class="pt-2 pb-2"></div><div class="chart-container" id="imem_ingess${i}_chart_container" style="position: relative; height:200rem; width:95vw; display: block;"><canvas id="imem_ingess${i}_chart" style="height: 30%; width: 30%;  display: block;"></canvas></div><div class="pt-4 pb-5"></div><div class="chart-container" id="imem_ingess${i}_chart_container2" style="position: relative; height:80rem; width:95vw; display: block;"><canvas id="imem_ingess${i}_chart2" style="height: 30%; width: 30%;  display: block;"></canvas></div></div>`;
            else block = `<div class="wrapper"><div class="gap" id="imem_egess${i - 16}"></div><div class="container"><div class='title'>IMEM egress ${i - 16} Graph</div><div class="description">hey2</div></div><div class="pt-2 pb-2"></div><div class="chart-container" id="imem_egess${i - 16}_chart_container" style="position: relative; height:200rem; width:95vw; display: block;"><canvas id="imem_egess${i - 16}_chart" style="height: 30%; width: 30%;  display: block;"></canvas></div><div class="pt-4 pb-5"></div><div class="chart-container" id="imem_egess${i - 16}_chart_container2" style="position: relative; height:80rem; width:95vw; display: block;"><canvas id="imem_egess${i - 16}_chart2" style="height: 30%; width: 30%;  display: block;"></canvas></div></div>`;

            await $('#imem_statistics_page').append(block);// will wait
        }

        //...
        console.log('End')
    }

    forLoop()

</script>
```

> Screenshot of test

[image]

> Related Link

[JavaScript async and await](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await/)

[Await in a for loop](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/)

Comment: `$('#imem_statistics_page').append(block);` will not return `promise` nor `apppend` is `async`, so you can not use `await` here. OP's code should work as expected without any change.

Comment: @Karan, you're right. From the provided code, I can't see any async process. That's why I post the code with const forLoop = async _ => {}. And also provide links about async. We can't tell that OP don't need async with the remaining code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an extra `u200b character`. And second, you can use `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
// doing async stuff
}, 1000);
```